# SSRS 2012 - chart label partial formatting: possible?

Tags: vba, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, formatting

I want to format a part of SSRS chat label.
Here is the code:

```
="Active: " & Format(Fields!ActiveMembers.Value, "###,###,###") & Environment.NewLine() & "Preserved: " & Format(Fields!PreservedMembers.Value, "###,###,###") & Environment.NewLine() & "Total: " & Format(Fields!TotalMembers.Value, "###,###,###")
```

Is it possible to make only last line appear in bold?
Different internet sources advise to change markup type to HTML, but that is only suitable for placeholders, could not find markup settings or any solution for chart labels.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's **not** a way to use **HTML** in a chart.

When you say **Label**, are you referring to the **Chart Title**? Your formula doesn't look like an **Axis label** and seems a bit wordy for a **Tool Tip**.

I usually do not use the Title and use a text box above the chart instead that **can** be formatted.